# Programmatically create a secure web http rest service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I would like to programmatically create a secure webhttp REST service in a self host environment i.e in a Console Application but i cannot find any tutorials which allow me to do this.

However i have created secure webhttp rest service using the WCF service library project without any C# code. I used netsh command to insert the certficiate that i had made and updated my config appropriately.

Can anyone advise please?

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick update, I got it working but only http side as of yet.

Here is my service side code:

```
 WebServiceHost serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(ProductServiceTest), new  Uri("http://localhost:9000/"));

        WebHttpBinding webHttpBinding = new WebHttpBinding();
        webHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536 * 2;
        webHttpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize=2147483647L; 
        webHttpBinding.MaxBufferSize=2147483647;
        webHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647L;

        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IProductServiceTest), webHttpBinding, "");



        // Check to see if the service host already has a ServiceMetadataBehavior
        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
        // If not, add one
        if (smb == null)
            smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
        serviceHost.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate the service host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        serviceHost.Close();
```

I created a console app for the client side and got my client side working by doing this:

```
ChannelFactory<IProductServiceTest> cf = new ChannelFactory<IProductServiceTest>(new WebHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:9000");
        cf.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        IProductServiceTest channel = cf.CreateChannel();
        var test = channel.GetProductData("8");
        Console.WriteLine(test.ProductDescription);
        Console.Read();
```